# is there a way to set time table to a process in windows services

Tags: windows, service

Is there a way to set time table to a process in windows services?
As in Scheduled Tasks I want to start and stop a service at a certain time.
any suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way we have done this, is to start and stop the thread at the required time. We had to do it just because we were not allowed to create scheduled tasks. Scheduled tasks are best for this kind of situation. Windows service will consume some CPU cycles even though the thread has nothing to do.

To start and stop a service you need some external component acting as kind of a monitor.

Prasad Pimparkar

Comment: Thanks. Since a script is needed to run/stop my process  I will use two schedule tasks . One for stopping the process and one for starting it.